# New command like \textcite but with only one author

Tags: biblatex, citing, author-number

I am using `biblatex` and a custom numeric-comp style for my references. I really like it the way it works but now I just want to have a new command which does the same as `\textcite` but truncates the number of authors to one.
That is

```
@BOOK{Steger2008,
author = {Carsten Steger and Markus Ulrich and Christian Wiedemann},
title = {Machine Vision Algorithms and Applications},
year = {2008}
}
```

gives with `\textcite{Steger2008}:
"Steger, Ulrich, and Wiedemann"`

It'd be great to have sth like `\shorttextcite{Steger2008}` that gives:
`"Steger et al."`

Is that possible - and how?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you still want `\textcite` to work as currently as well (e.g. for the first mention of a work)?

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
Yes, I want to stay with the old \textcite and get a new command \newtextcite as already mentioned by henrique. I don't want to change the variable globally.

Since I do not work with the authoryear citation style but with a (slightly customized) version of numeric-comp I am unsure how to get this work for the other style. I tried to look in the CTAN code but am unabable to understand where to inlcude the line you mentioned above.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
Any ideas on how to tackle this for the numeric-comp citation style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks again henrique. With your help I could figure out how to solve this for the numeric-comp style.
I can now use \shorttextcite{} for a textcite with only one author + et al.
I copied the code from the textcite definition of numeric-comp and added the line from henrique.
Here are the lines I added to my *.cbx file:

```
    % shorttextcite definition
    \DeclareCiteCommand{\cbx@shorttextcite}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:init}}
      {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
       \usebibmacro{textcite}}
      {}
      {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
       \usebibmacro{postnote}%
       \ifbool{cbx:parens}
         {\bibclosebracket\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
         {}}

    \DeclareCiteCommand{\shorttextcite}[\cbx@shorttextcite@init\cbx@shorttextcite]
      {\gdef\cbx@savedkeys{}%
       \citetrackerfalse%
       \pagetrackerfalse%
       \DeferNextCitekeyHook%
       \usebibmacro{cite:init}}
      {\ifthenelse{\iffirstcitekey\AND\value{multicitetotal}>0}
         {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{()(\thefield{multipostnote})}%
          \global\clearfield{multipostnote}}
         {}%
       \xappto\cbx@savedkeys{\thefield{entrykey},}%
       \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
         {}
         {\stepcounter{textcitetotal}%
          \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}
      {}
      {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{%
         [\thefield{prenote}][\thefield{postnote}]{\cbx@savedkeys}}}

    \newrobustcmd{\cbx@shorttextcite@init}[2]{%
        \numdef\blx@maxcitenames{1}% <--- Here.
      \setcounter{textcitetotal}{0}%
      \setcounter{textcitecount}{0}%
      \def\cbx@savedcites{#1}#2\cbx@savedcites\empty}

    \DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cbx@shorttextcites}{\cbx@shorttextcite}{}
    \DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\shorttextcites}[\cbx@shorttextcites@init\cbx@shorttextcites]{\shorttextcite}{}
```

Answer (score 11):

`maxcitenames` is the option that affects the maximum number of authors that appear in citations. It's set initially to the same value as `maxnames`, which defines the maximum number of authors both in the bibliography and in citations (as stated in Tobjørn T.'s comment to Dror answer).

So, if you want to globally set citations to print only one author, this is the option you're looking for, and `\usepackage[maxcitenames=1]{biblatex}` suffices.

But if you want to have this option set to 1 locally within a single citation command, you must define a new one and change the `maxcitenames` option internally.

`maxcitenames`option sets the var `\blx@maxcitenames`. Redefining it within the scope of your new citation command suffices.

Here, I copied the definition of `textcite` from the `authoryear` citation style and added `\numdef\blx@maxcitenames{1}` to its `precode` section:

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\newtextcite}
  {\numdef\blx@maxcitenames{1}% <--- Here.
  \boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \iffirstcitekey
     {\setcounter{textcitetotal}{1}}
     {\stepcounter{textcitetotal}%
      \textcitedelim}%
   \usebibmacro{textcite}}
  {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
     {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
     {}}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\newtextcites}{\newtextcite}{}
\makeatother
```

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\newtextcite}
  {\numdef\blx@maxcitenames{1}
  \boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \iffirstcitekey
     {\setcounter{textcitetotal}{1}}
     {\stepcounter{textcitetotal}%
      \textcitedelim}%
   \usebibmacro{textcite}}
  {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
     {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
     {}}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\newtextcites}{\newtextcite}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\textcites{companion,padhye,sorace,laufenberg}

\newtextcites{companion,padhye,sorace,laufenberg}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

<sup>Notice that the default value for `maxnames` and `maxcitenames` is set to 3 (that's why the `laufenberg` entry is shortened in both examples)</sup>

Comment: You an also set these options per-entry in the .bib itself - `OPTIONS= {maxcitenames=1}` etc.

Comment: @PLK do you think I should address this in the answer?

Comment: This would also change it globally for the whole text.

Comment: In addition, you can set `maxcitenames=2,mincitenames=1` to truncate the authors "A, B and C" to "A et al.", but keep "A and B" as is. For more options see the [package docs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) (obviously)

Answer (score 4):

Try to set `maxnames=1` in the package's options. In particular, use

```
\usepackage[maxnames=1]{biblatex}
```

in your preamble.

Comment: This will also truncate the author list in the bibliography, `maxcitenames=1` only affects citations.